# Angular 4 In Code override Bootstrap colors globally

Tags: css, angular, styling

I am looking to create a dynamic coloring system with Angular. I created a service that has 4 strings,success, info, warning, danger with defaults of their color codes. I want to at the root of my application which I assume is at app.component because I am using routing to inject this service and override globally

```
.btn-warning {
    color: #fff; <-- Inject my own color like so (color: AppSettings.ColorSettings.Warning)
    background-color: #f0ad4e; <-- Inject my own color 
    border-color: #f0ad4e; <-- Inject my own color 
}
```

I want this to be dynamic so that if the user went into a settings panel could change these colors and in real time see the effect in every place that uses those classes.

I see `[ngStyle]` but that applies specific things like colors to just one element. 
I also see `[ngClass]` but I don't know how to create class that is more like a way to apply a class to an element.

Could I do something like so?

```
<html>
<!-- Junk ^ with bootstrap up here -->
<style>{{GetColorSettings()}}</style>
<!-- More stuff -->
</html>
```

Comment: You can create a shared service and toggle between css classes binding to `[ngClass]` depending on the event triggered when user changes color options from settings or other places

Comment: I don't understand how to apply my own color to for example the .btn-warning class in a global way without having to apply ngClass to a bunch of tags

Comment: if you define the css classes in the `style.css` file (which should be at the root level) then it should be globally available throughout your application

Comment: Missing the words dynamic and in code,I don't want to hard code them and I have a working example I will post soon.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant solution however I really like it for how easy it will be to setup. Inside of my app.component I have this setup. Within the GenerateColorSettings method you will need to define all the different colors, which will require me expanding my classes inside of ColorSettings further. Some of the effects are default, :hover, :disabled

```
constructor(public infoService: InformationService, private configSettings: GlobalConfigSettings)
  {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = this.GenerateColorSettings();
    style.id = "DynamicColors"
    document.body.appendChild(style);


    setTimeout(() =>{
      configSettings.ColorSettings.warning = "#fff";
      configSettings.ColorSettings.ColorsChanged.emit();
    }, 25000);

    configSettings.ColorSettings.ColorsChanged.subscribe(() =>
    { 
      var style = document.getElementById('DynamicColors');
      style.innerHTML = this.GenerateColorSettings();
    });    

  }



  private GenerateColorSettings(): string
  {
    console.log("Getting color");
    return `.btn-warning{
      color: #fff;
      background-color: ${this.configSettings.ColorSettings.warning};
      border-color: ${this.configSettings.ColorSettings.warning};
    }

    .btn-warning:hover{
      color: #fff;
      background-color: ${this.configSettings.ColorSettings.warning};
      border-color: ${this.configSettings.ColorSettings.warning};
    }
    `;
  }
```